# Isn't Java recursive?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm mainly used to Python, and I'm learning Java. I want to access a class variable and I've been told I have to make an instance of the class inside a class function, like

```java
public class Main {
    public int myint;
    public static void mainl(String [] args)
    {
        Main myObject = new Main();
        myObject.myint = 5;
        System.out.println("wow print");
    }
}
```

If I'm making an instance of the main class inside the object itself wouldn't that be infinitely recursive?

Python comparison

```py
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 5
        A = main()
        print(A.num)
main()
```

Python output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\new_multi_test\comp.py", line 7, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\new_multi_test\comp.py", line 4, in __init__
    A = main()
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\new_multi_test\comp.py", line 4, in __init__
    A = main()
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\new_multi_test\comp.py", line 4, in __init__
    A = main()
  [Previous line repeated 509 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

How is this possibly working in Java?

Comment: In your Python example, the Python constructor creates another instance of the class, which recurses infinitely. In your Java example there is only a default constructor, which does nothing except initialise `myInt` to a default value (zero).

Comment: A static class method (as in your Java example) is not the same as a constructor (as in your Python example).

Comment: `static` methods in Java are similar to `@staticmethod` methods in Python. You don't need an instance of the class to call them. Also, `__init__` in Python is similar to a _constructor_ in Java. Your Java code does not have a constructor.

Comment: I don't know Python but I'll echo what the other comments say.  `mainl` (I assume that's a typo and you meant `main`) is *just* a static method, and here it's used as the entry point for the whole program.  Basically the same as the `main` entry point in C or C++.  Just something called by the OS and that's it.  Java could have the same infinite recursion as your Python example, except the code you have for Java doesn't do that.  The `main` method isn't auto executed or invoked in any fashion when a new instance of `Main` is created. (And the spelling mistake wouldn't change that.)

Answer (score 4):

Your two programs are not equivalent. Not even close.

---

Your python code is equivalent to the following Java code:

```
public class Main {
    public int myint;

    public Main() { // __init__ in python
        this.myint = 5;
        Main A = new Main();
        System.out.println(A.myint);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new Main(); // main() in python
    }
}
```

And this Java code will throw an exception just as you'd expect:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:6)
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:6)
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:6)
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:6)
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:6)
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:6)
    ...
```

StackoverflowErrors is thrown when your recursion gets too deep.

---

And looking at your original Java code, here's the equivalent python code:

```
class main():
  pass

myObject = main()
myObject.myint = 5
print("wow print");
```

You see, there's no recursion, just an empty class that gets instantiated and then assigned an attribute value before printing some unrelated text.